# Не получается изменить фон div по наведению на другой тег Qjuary

Tags: jquery

```
<style>
div#room{
background:background: url(../img/room.jpg);
}
</style>

<div id = "room">
//............
</div>
<img src = "img/tv.png" class = "tv">

<script>
$(".tv").on("mouseover",function(){
$("#room").css("background","url(../img/roo.jpg)").css("background-size","100% 100%");
});
$(".tv").on("mouseout",function(){
$("#room").css("background","url(../img/room.jpg)").css("background-size","100% 100%");
});
</script>
```

Есть такой код, по наведению на картинку просто исчезает начальный фон, но 
нужный(roo.jpg) так и не появляется

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде получается.

```js
$(".tv").on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#room").css("background-image", "url(https://mf.by/upload/resize_cache/iblock/8c0/900_425_1d7a58ff99b324185ccb5ad5dfbdb5e85/8c008f4eef3664f1e0a70f3988a2558a.jpg)");
});
$(".tv").on("mouseout", function() {
  $("#room").css("background-image", "");
});
```

```css
#room {
  background: url(http://samdizajner.ru/wp-content/uploads/detskaja_dlja_podrostka-2.jpg) no-repeat center/cover;
  height:100px;
  transition:all .3s ease;
}
.tv{
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="room"></div>
<img src="https://img.mvideo.ru/Pdb/10009295b2.jpg" class="tv">
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема в url пути  была.

Comment: @Artem , бывает. И, это, когда на JQuery несколько css свойств у элемента меняешь там синтаксис немного другой: `$("elem").css({"свойство":"значение", "свойство":"значение"})`